# Azure LogicApp - SQL Get modified rows filter

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a LogicApp which has a "SQL Get modified rows" trigger. I want to add a filter to the SQL so it only collects rows where the Reference column starts `'O'`. My understanding is I can use `startsWith`, but this returns a Syntax error.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, my syntax was wrong, it should have been...

```
startswith(Reference, 'O')
```